# How to measure the accuracy of a digital multimeter when we don't have its datasheet?

Tags: multimeter, accuracy

Is it possible to measure the accuracy of a measured value by a digital multimeter without referring to its datasheet?

Comment: Only if you have something to calibrate it with - precision resistors, voltage sources etc.

Comment: With what I can calibrate the voltage sources?

Comment: @user96402: with an even more precise voltage source and/or measurement device.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - And yes, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: at the bottom the turtles are called electrons and we count them one by one ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH Sorry, but those who make an even more precise voltage source how measure their error?

Comment: @user96402: by using the quantum mechanical definition of the volt that is based on single electrons and use of devices that are essentially single electron charge pumps driven by precise frequencies.

Comment: You could have the meter calibrated by a company that specializes in this.  I think our company pays about $70 to calibrate each of our Fluke meters every year.

Comment: There's a potentially very interesting question here about references and error. In the meantime, have a look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/learning-about-voltage-references

Comment: @tcrosley: I once visited a company that did that too, with many multimeters. A quick math showed that buying a 732a, calibrating that once a year, and then using that to calibrate the meters was saving them tons of money.

Comment: @pjc50: but that intresting question is really struggling to get out...

Comment: @PlasmaHH That would work, except UL wouldn't look kindly at us doing our own calibrations.  (Wheres the sticker?)  Darn regulations.

Comment: @tcrosley: If you need that, calculate the cost for being able to officially calibrate stuff too...

Comment: @PlasmaHH We only have to calibrate a couple of meters to keep UL happy.  All of our others are marked "Calibration Not Required" as they are not used for critical work.  Small company.  Just two hardware engineers, and a bunch of firmware engineers.  They use the non-calibrated ones.  They get the cheaper scopes too.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You measure the voltage of a 'prevision voltage reference'. They are sold pre-calibrated to the right voltage.

If you have a cheap 3.5-digit multimeter you can use cheap 0.1% reference: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2200. Note that it is calibrated at the factory.